# Android Custom Title Bar Button Text incomplete display

Tags: android, android-layout

I have defined the following layout for the title bar in my android app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id = "@+id/CustomTitleRelativeLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTvCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clearcachebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/clear_cache_button_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my button is not getting displayed completely. Can anyone help me where I'm going wrong.

The display is as follows:

[image]

In the title bar , as you can see the button Text is not shown correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/CustomTitleRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTvCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Please add code of all layout, but not only top panel(Title Bar).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Button` uses `fill_parent` for layout height. When its parent is set to `wrap_content`, it will wrap only what is necessary. Since the button simply matches that instead of insisting it wraps its own content, it gets chopped.

Just change the Button height to `wrap_content` and you'll be set.

I assume this is what Artyom was saying with that answer, but it's not very clear.